# Why does "import requests" fail in atom but not a console?

Tags: python, atom-editor, jupyter, hydrogen

I have a basic python script that starts with

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import difflib
import re
```

When I run that first block via [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>), I get an attribute error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-686486c241c8> in <module>()
----> 1 import requests
/home/amanda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py in <module>()
     51 # Attempt to enable urllib3's SNI support, if possible
     52 try:
---> 53     from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
     54     pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()
     55 except ImportError:
/home/amanda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in <module>()
     91 }
     92 
---> 93 DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST = util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS
     94 
     95 # OpenSSL will only write 16K at a time
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS'AttributeError
'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS'
```

But if I launch a python console, `import requests` works fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: i tend to think that you are using different versions of python

Comment: Okay ... so any tips on confirming that and addressing it?

Comment: check what python version uses your console and Hydrogen, i guess it's going to be python 2.7 for console and some version of ipython for Hydrogen and i don't remember seeing requests for ipython

Comment: @minitoto: ipython is not a version of Python, it's a program/library that uses Python.

Comment: @BrenBarn ipython is a shell and it might use different version of python and it's embedded into Hydrogen

Comment: Tried to switch over to ipython notebook for this project and I'm doing something wonky there, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374917/where-is-ipython-notebook-hiding