# Where is ipython notebook hiding?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have not used `ipython-notebook` in a while and I think I'm doing something wonky. When I launch it (with `ipython notebook`) I get a web interface that lets me edit files in the browser: [image: screenshot]  but the menus are all MIA there's no way to run anything or add new cells.

I suspect that I'm missing something very simple and obvious, here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a new notebook.
Navigate back to `http://localhost:8888/tree`, browse to the folder where you want to create it, and then use the `New` menu on the right:

[image]